# Want to send client's screen image at periodic interval though applet. Java

Tags: java, applet

I am using applet that is embedded in my web page. I am using Robot class to get client's screen as a image and send the `BufferedImage` using sockets. Problem is i am getting `PrivilegedAccessException` as soon as i do :-

```
Robot r = new Robot();
```

I don't want to force my user to change their java policies for my application. What alternatives do i have to capture client's screen?

Secondly, if i run my application directly from Netbeans 6.8 (not from web page), i get error that `BufferedImage` is not `Serializable` when i write an object of `BufferedImage` to socket. How to get rid of this problem?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: partial duplicate of [help for solving problems in a java rmi assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227758/help-for-solving-problems-in-a-java-rmi-assignment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a signed jar with your applet and the permissions you need on the client machine. You can [read more here](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html). The applet will then ask the user if he/she trusts the applet before allowing it to be run.

For the serializable bit, you'll have to convert the BufferedImage to a serializable file. If you have to do that you can just as well compress it using PNG. This will speedup the transfer a lot, usually an order of magnitude.[Here is more info](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html) about that.